# Set class of hidden input created by @html.checkboxfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, checkboxfor

i have a view where i dynamically add/ delete checkboxes in a table. I´m using the mvc4 razor engine in my view. With the synatx `@Html.CheckboxFor(m=>m.xyz)` razor creates two input fields. One with the type `checkbox` and one with type `hidden`. If i give a class to the checkbox with `@Html.CheckboxFor(m=>m.xyz, new {@class= "CheckboxClass})` only the input field with type `checkbox`get this class. Is there a easy way to give the class to both input fields?

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do that?  CSS is for *styling*.  hidden inputs have no visual component, thus nothing for css to operate on.

Comment: I need the value of the input for my model. All the checkboxes are parts of a list and if i delete a checkbox i need to give a new `name` to all checkboxes to ensure the texture of the model. The easiest way to do so is to modify all input fields with the same `class`.

Comment: your checkboxes already have the class.  The hidden field is to ensure a value gets sent back.. so let it do its job.  If you delete a checkbox client side you will get the default value back server side.  No big deal.

Comment: If i have a list in my model, mvc uses the name of the fields for postback. For example List[0].ID for an object on index 0 with attribute ID. So every input field to send to server have to got the same index if from the same element. If i delete for example element with index 4 i have to set all higher indexes -1. In the case of the checkbox btw it sends the hidden input to the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't like just leaving things the way they are, then you have a couple options.

- make the input fields yourself.. you are working in an HTML file after all.
- write some javascript to handle it:

`$('.chkClass').each(i,e) {`
`$('INPUT[name=' + e.name + ' type=hidden]').remove();`
`});  //untested, and it's very late here.`